How to make the date added by VBA refresh immediately?
I used the following code to add header and footer for a sheet,
Sub Header()
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = "xxxxxxxxxx Corp."
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = "Page:" & Chr(10) & "Prepared by/Date:" & Chr(10) & "Reviewed by/Date:"
        .CenterFooter = "&[Tab]" & Chr(10) & "&[File]"
        .RightFooter = "&[Time]" & Chr(10) & "&[Date]"
    End With
End Sub

but the date and time do not update automatically. I have to click it manually, and it always displays like this (before clicking).

Can it refresh immediately after the macro runs?
I always click it by myself after the macro run.

Do you mean something like that
.CenterFooter = "&A" & Chr(10) & "&F"
.RightFooter = "&T" & Chr(10) & "&D"

You need to use special formatting codes in VBA for the header and footer properties.
You will find the documentation here and a similar post
